# Eliminar marca de error en código SQL luego de aplicar un Alter a una tabla #temporal

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

como puedo evitar que el editor de SQL Server me indique como error un campo de de una tabla temporal al escribir la sentencia SELECT. Dejo el ejemplo para que puedan ver:

```
CREATE TABLE [#Tmp_Oportunidades]
    ([Cliente] Int NULL             
    , [CodigoFiscal] Varchar(255) NULL  
    , [Titulo] Varchar(255) NULL            
    , [Empleado] Int NULL
    , [IdCategoria] Int NULL            
    , [CesionTipo] Varchar(255) NULL    
    , [IdCampaña] Int NULL) 

ALTER TABLE [#Tmp_Oportunidades] ADD [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [Fila_Error] NVarchar(4000) NULL` `

INSERT INTO [#Tmp_Oportunidades] ([CesionTipo], [Fila_Error]) values ('N','aaa')
```

El campo [Fila_Error] me aparece marcado como error, a pesar que al ejecutar el script funciona bien. ¿Hay alguna forma de actualizar el Objeto temporal en la base de datos desde el código T-SQL?

Comment: Por qué tiene que ALTER y no añadir las filas en el CREATE?

Comment: Sobre el final del alter tienes dos comillas que nada tienen que ver con esta sentencia, además la clausula de insert esta incompleta.

Comment: por que el create es para ser utilizado con un bulk insert, y luego tengo que modificar la tabla temporal, las comillas estan de más, fue un error al pegar el codigo aqui en el post,